# I do not understand robocopy report

Tags: robocopy

I am using the following command:

```
robocopy "h:/.backup-ship/" "../.backup-ship/" /MIR /NDL /MT
```

robocopy report writes:

[image]

I do not understand the row "Files". Should not be the column "Total" 9051 and column "Skipped" is 9050? It seems those values are mixed.

(btw I tried to get the version information of robocopy I am using to provide here as detailed information, and realized I can not see it anywhere..., maybe I missed something...)

Comment: Can you show us the entire command? Could a log file have been outputted during? i.e. it takes the total count at first run or something.

Comment: I've edited the OP to include the command I was issued